# Pandas - return a dataframe after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas `df`:

```
Name    No
A       1
A       2
B       2
B       2
B       3
```

I want to group by column `Name`, sum column `No` and then return a 2-column dataframe like this:

```
Name    No
A       3
B       7
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['Name'])['No'].sum()
```

but it does not return my desire dataframe. I can't add the result to a dataframe as a column.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add parameter `as_index=False` to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Name'], as_index=False)['No'].sum())
  Name  No
0    A   3
1    B   7
```

Or call [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['Name'])['No'].sum().reset_index())
  Name  No
0    A   3
1    B   7
```